# converting to expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, stirling-numbers

Let us recall that the Stirling numbers satisfy the identities:
$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle{ n \brace k} &= \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j}{k \choose j} j^n = \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j {k \choose j}(k-j)^n
\\[6pt]
{ n+1 \brace k} &= k{ n \brace k} + { n \brace k-1}
\end{align}$$

and appear in the Taylor expansion:
$$\frac{(e^w-1)^k}{k!} = \sum_{n=k}^\infty { n \brace k}\frac{w^n}{n!}.$$

i am confused about the last equation.
through researching, ive done converting $(e^w-1)^k$ into a binomial expansion then i got $∑(−1)^{k−j} \binom k j e^{jw}$ and convert $e^{jw}$ then i dont know how to multiply or do some mathematical operations with sigma notation, i dont know what is next..how can i convert that into $$\frac{(e^w-1)^k}{k!} = \sum_{n=k}^\infty { n \brace k}\frac{w^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: [Duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876663/taylor-expansion-of-an-stirling-identity).

Comment: hi @KennyLau yes i know that it is the same question but could you help me what is the next step??

Comment: @daphne: This question already has an *[answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876663/taylor-expansion-of-an-stirling-identity/1876813#1876813)*.

Comment: oh thanks for making me aware, but could you give me please another solution(if it's okay for you)? like what i have started,

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{(e^{w}-1)^{k}}{k!}&=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}e^{jw}=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(jw)^{m}}{m!} \\
&=
\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}\frac{(jw)^{m}}{m!}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}j^{m}\right)\frac{w^{m}}{m!}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { m \brace k}\frac{w^{m}}{m!}=\sum_{m=k}^{\infty} { m \brace k}\frac{w^{m}}{m!}
\end{align}